# Where does YouTube save the videos when I click the save button?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

When I am using YouTube in a web browser and I click on the save button for a video, how do I find it later?

For example, if I save a video under the tag "Recipes", where can I find that tag in YouTube later?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving them to the **Recipes** *playlist* therefore you would need to access that playlist in order to find the saved video.

Your playlists can be accessed in several different ways including:

1. They are listed in the hamburger menu under

   ```
    You > Show More > "playlist name"
   ```
2. They can be accessed if you know the playlist's URL. For example, the built-in **Watch Later** playlist can always be accessed at **[`www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL`](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL)**
3. You can also access your playlists by appending `/playlists` to your Youtube channel URL.
    For example, if your YouTube channel is:

   ```
   www.youtube.com/@Ole2514
   ```

   Your direct link to your playlists will be:

   ```
   www.youtube.com/@Ole2514/playlists
   ```